# How to handle IOException when closing bufferedReader

Tags: java, ioexception

Hi I am learning about Exceptions in Java and I encountered a problem with this situation.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String path = "t.txt";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try{
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        StringBuilder sbd = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null){
            sbd.append(line);
            sbd.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        String result = sbd.toString();   
        System.out.print(result);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        if (br != null) 
            br.close(); //Here it says unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    }
}
```

when I call method close() to close the bufferedReader, it says unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.

I know that JAVA 7 provides a pretty easy way to do the clean-up with

```
 try(br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))){
//.... 
}
```

but prior to JAVA 7, what can I do with this situation? adding "throws IOException" right next to the main function declaration is a way to fix that but is it a little bit complicated since I have had a catch section to catch IOExceptions

Answer (score 4):

You wrapped it into another `try-catch`

```
}finally{
    if (br != null) 
        try {
            br.close(); //Here it says unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }
}
```

Now, if you care or not is another question.  To my mind, your intention here is to make all best effort to close the resource.  If you want, you could use flag and set it to `true` in the parent `catch` block (indicating that any following errors should be ignored) and if it's `false` in the close `catch` block, display an error message, for example...

```
boolean hasErrored = false;
try {
    //...
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    hasErrored = true;
}finally{
    if (br != null) 
        try {
            br.close(); //Here it says unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            if (!hasErrored) {
                // Display error message...
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: That's a very detailed answer. So in practice, which is the best solution for using resources like bufferedReader and catching the possible exceptions? Like what would you do to handle this situation?

Comment: It comes down to needs.  Personally, I generally ignore the `close` errors, cause by then, it's most likely that an error has already occurred before hand, but there's nothing wrong with adding in some additional information if you need it.  What you want to avoid is displaying/reporting multiple errors which are connected, ie, couldn't close  the file because the read failed, but that's me

Comment: Thank you very much! then if I use the Java7 solution, do I still need worry about the possible exception of using close() even though it is called implicitly?

Comment: No!  And I can tell you `try-with-resources` is one of the best reasons to start using Java 7+!

Answer (score 2):

> prior to JAVA 7, what can I do with this situation?

You can add a `try-catch` in the `finally` block like,

```
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle the IOException on close by doing nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So in Java7 by using "try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)))" does it automatically handle the possible exception when using close()?

Comment: The [`try-with-resources` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) reads (in part) *However, in this example, if the methods readLine and close both throw exceptions, then the method readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock throws the exception thrown from the finally block; the exception thrown from the try block is suppressed.*

Comment: Thanks! so generally is it a bad thing if the exception thrown from the try block is suppressed?  I just want to find the best way to handle the possible exceptions of using resources

Comment: Perhaps, but the code has made a good faith effort to `close()` the resource. If you want to add a `throws IOException` to your method signature you could, but I don't think it's a good practice to throw (or re-throw) an `Exception` for a resource that's now out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

add another try catch block

```
 ... 
    if(br != null)
       try{
            br.close();
       } catch (IOException io){
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally code it thus:

```
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try { 
            br.close();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, I once wrote a util class containing methods such as `closeStream(final InputStream stream)`, `closeStream(final OutputStream stream)`, `closeReader(final Reader reader)`, etc that hides all this stuff, since you end up using it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This is approximately how try-with-resources closes resources

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    IOException ex = null;
    try {
        br.read();
        // ...
    } catch(IOException e) {
        ex = e;
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close(); // close quietly
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (ex != null) {
                ex.addSuppressed(e);
            } else {
                ex = e;
            }
        }
    }
    if (ex != null) {
        throw ex;
    }
```